# how to show clear image on matplotlib axes and how to fit rectangle perfectly on axes on dynamic change?

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, wxwidgets

Here, I am displaying boy's image on matplotlib figure but is not displaying clear image.

My first question is, how to code to avoid blurriness and display clear image on axes?

Also, I am drawing rectangle on axes using on_Hori() and on_vert() function and changing its position dynamically.

My second question, is there any other best way to code rectangle directly on self.axes_animation apart from calling plt.Rectangle()?

My third question is, when i am drawing upper rectangle i.e self.p_rect (Horizontally) then it is going outside the figure. Is it possible to extend the x-axes limits automatically so that rectangle will fit inside the figure perfectly.

```
import wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas, FigureCanvasWxAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

import time

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.vert_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        '''Start of middle_tool_box to initialize plotanimation'''
        middle_tool_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.figure_animation = Figure(figsize=(6, 6))
        self.axes_animation = self.figure_animation.subplots()

        self.p_rect = plt.Rectangle(xy= (500, 100), width=10, height=100,fill=False)
                                                    #fill=True, color='black', ec='black')
        self.axes_animation.add_patch(self.p_rect)

        self.l_rect = plt.Rectangle(xy=(500, 300), width=10, height=100, fill=False)
        # fill=True, color='black', ec='black')
        self.axes_animation.add_patch(self.l_rect)


        self.women_img2 = mpimg.imread('Boy.png')
        self.show_img = self.axes_animation.imshow(self.women_img2)  # interpolation='nearest' for clear image
        self.canvas_animation = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self, -1, self.figure_animation)

        # self.axes_animation.set_axis_off()
        self.axes_animation.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=True)
        self.axes_animation.axis('tight')
        middle_tool_box.Add(self.canvas_animation, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        P_L_Hori = wx.Button(self, label='P_L_Hori')
        P_L_Vert = wx.Button(self, label='P_L_Vert')

        self.mainSizer.Add(P_L_Hori, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 1)
        self.mainSizer.Add(P_L_Vert, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 1)
        middle_tool_box.Add(self.mainSizer)
        self.vert_box.Add(middle_tool_box, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 1)
        '''End of middle_tool_box'''
        P_L_Hori.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_Hori)
        P_L_Vert.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_Vert)


        self.SetSizer(self.vert_box)
        self.Refresh()

    def on_Hori(self,e):
        print("on_Hori")
        try:
            if hasattr(self, "p_rect"):
                self.p_rect.remove()
            if hasattr(self, "l_rect"):
                self.l_rect.remove()
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            self.l_rect = plt.Rectangle(xy=(450, 150), width=100, height=10, fill=False)
            self.p_rect = plt.Rectangle(xy=(350, 350), width=100, height=10, fill=False)
            self.axes_animation.add_patch(self.p_rect)
            self.axes_animation.add_patch(self.l_rect)
            self.canvas_animation.draw()

    def on_Vert(self,e):
        print("on_Hori")
        try:
            if hasattr(self, "p_rect"):
                self.p_rect.remove()
            if hasattr(self, "l_rect"):
                self.l_rect.remove()
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            self.l_rect = plt.Rectangle(xy=(500, 100), width=10, height=100, fill=False)
            self.p_rect = plt.Rectangle(xy=(500, 300), width=10, height=100, fill=False)
            self.axes_animation.add_patch(self.p_rect)
            self.axes_animation.add_patch(self.l_rect)
            self.canvas_animation.draw()


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Test', size=(750, 550))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image: Download Boy.png here]

Please guide me in solving my listed issues.
Thank you.

Comment: do you have a HiDPI monitor? What wxPython/python version do you use? What platform?

Comment: @Igor I am using '4.0.4 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5' wxpython version. yes I am using  HiDPI monitor. Do you know what is the problem related to image and also related to other  listed issues? Thank you for the response.

Comment: you might want to sed an E-mail to the wxpython ML. Ask if the appropriate manifest is included i the wxpython distribution to work with HiDPI. I'm sure it is but I don't know. Also - it might be a problem with the plotting - matplotlib may not support HiDPI (with your version of it). Ask on their ML as well. Sorry - I'm more C++ guy...